# Please don't plagiarize text for tag wikis

Tags: discussion

I've been going through recent edit suggestions, and I noticed that a few users are being dedicated in their tag curation. That's fantastic; thank you. However, I've *also* noticed that some content is taken word-for-word from outside sources (sometimes Wikipedia, sometimes other sites), often without attribution. That's plagiarism, plain and simple.

It's also true that copying-and-pasting content from elsewhere [is usually not the best course of action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81047/274942) - even with attribution. There are better ways to summarize relevant information in a tag wiki, and they don't involve copying someone else's work. In fact, there's a Reject option for tag wiki suggested edits for this reason:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community specifically](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

See also [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337/274942).

Please don't plagiarize. It doesn't help the site.

Comment: Guilty. Thanks for pointing that out. **Is it possible to just combine information from different sources and list them at the bottom?** Because I see no way of typing a tag wiki by yourself without referencing all the sources. Also, we would need medical experts in all fields for that.

Comment: @Narusan That's a possibility, although tag wikis (with the exception of some on SO) usually aren't that long. Entries shouldn't be encyclopedic.